# PHP with mssql connection fail (windows auth)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect from php to a mssql database. 
I have already install the drivers for this.

Now I'm havig the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ) )

Is there anything I'm missing?

Edit:
My connection string:

```
$serverName = "server, port";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"my_database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn == false)
 {
 echo "Unable to connect.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
```

Edit 2:

Code sample with user and pw

```
$serverName = "server, port"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"my_database", "UID"=>"domain\user", "PWD"=>"my_pw");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection OK.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Unable to connect.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Zhorov added the code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify the authentication method in the wampapaches service. There I put my user and pass and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have a php script to access a mssql database hosted by a vendor.  We can't use Windows Authentication.  The userid and password are valid since it works with python. We found that the password the vendor provided contains a $, which in PHP indicates a variable. We changed the double quotes around the password to single quotes and it worked. And this was caused by the server having Magic Quotes turned on and the workaround is to use single quotes forcing PHP to recognize the password as a string.